# Basic regexp question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I am using this as my validation regexp for name fields.

How can I modify this to also check for minimum of 2 characters?

```
'/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]+$/'
```

I use it like so:

```
if(name_exp.test($("#"+name_input).val())){ Everything is OK! }
```

Comment: I mean, so there is atleast 2 characters in the string to check against? Isn't that possible?

Comment: Yes, see below. Your wording confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick: {2,} will require 2 or more characters
http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

```
/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]{2,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]{2,}$/'
```

Should do it: `{2,}` is the condition of at least 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the "one ore more" operator (`+`) try specifying "two or more" (`{2,}`):

```
/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]{2,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]{2,}$/
```

*{n}* will match exactly *n* characters, *{n,}* will match *n* or more, and *{m,n}* will match between *m* and *n*